# Visibility of markers on map/panorama in google maps

Tags: google-maps-api-3

My skills in Google Maps Api  and JavaScript are limited so mybe I can get some help from you.

I have a marker that is visible both on the map and street view/panorama.
Is there a way to hide the marker on the map but still have it visible in the street view/panorama?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the map-container if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the `visible`-property of the Marker to the `visible`-property of the StreetView

```
marker.bindTo('visible',map.streetView,'visible');
```